# Infinite scroll isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, infinite-scroll

I Have been going through a tutorial on infinite scrolling and have everything exactly the same except my alert is not being triggered and I cannot work out why. Any possible variations of obtaining the scroll positioning in the IF statement would also be helpful.

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");
$results = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY image_name DESC LIMIT 0,2");
$count = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM images");
$nbr = $count->rowCount();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class='images'>
        <?php
            while($row = $results->fetch())
            {
                ?>
                <p><img src="images/<?php echo $row['image_name'];?>" height="500" width="500"></p>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
        </div>

    <script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var load = 0;
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
                {
                    alert("test");
                }
            });
        });         
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look in the browser's error console. Do you see any errors?

Comment: Try `>=` in the `if` condition. Scrolling ins't typically pixel-by-pixel, so you could just be scrolling past where they would be `==`.

Comment: No errors are displayed and I have tried the >= without any success.

Comment: also try `$(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())`

Comment: Do you actually get a scrollbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The correct library needs to be called which many sites do not stipulate. Here is the code that needs to be posted just before the scroll script.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```